# How to change list[a] with list[b] in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

how can I change mylist[0] with mylist[1]:

```
mylist = [2,5]
```

after change:

```
mylist = [5,2]
```

Comment: That's too trivial...

Comment: Do you want to switch specific indexes or you want to reverse a list?

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution:

```
mylist[:] = miylist[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's ridiculously trivial:

```
tmp = mylist[0]
mylist[0] = mylist[1]
mylist[1] = tmp
```

You can access an item at a given index with `list[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a temp variable in python.

```
mylist[0],mylist[1] = mylist[1],mylist[0]
```

Can be used.